# Circle Spinning about its axis

Tags: svg, axis, geometry

I want to make a circle rotate about its axis but this is what it is doing right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <circle cx="150" cy="20" r = 10 fill="blue">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    from="0 180 50"
                    type="rotate"
                    to="360 180 50"
                    dur="4s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </circle>  
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>'
```

Comment: What do you mean? Circles don't have an axis, exactly how do you want this to rotate?

Comment: if you rotate a circle about its origin it won't appear to change.

Comment: I would like to add things onto the circle so that it appears to spin.